# Android- How to show progress bar in one Activity till the upload task completes in Another Activity

Tags: android

I have an **Activity 1**, where i am uploading an image. When the upload starts i need to switch to another **Activity 2** and show a *progress bar* till upload task in Activity 1 completes. Also i need to hide the *progress bar* once the upload completes in **Activity 1**. Please Assist

Comment: Well that is my question, can we able to show a progress bar in the next Activity 2.

Comment: https://github.com/oznus/UploadManager use this library for async task

Comment: Thank you Rajesh...i will check in that and let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you need an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` to handle uploading image
2. Next you need to define an `interface` which contains 2 base methods `onUploadStarted()` and `onUploadFinished()`, your Async`T`ask (or Thread) will call these mothods.

   3. `Activity2` implements `onUploadStarted()` and `onUploadFinished()` method.

Comment: Thanks phan...It will be so much helpful...if u gove a small example...if possible